# TFS2018 Build definition save error - Counter with name %counterName="BuildFolderId";% does not exist

Tags: sql, build, build-definition

i have a problem with a newly migrated TFS On-permise from 2015update1 to 2018update2

I create a new build definition, and when i click on "save", i have the following message:

```
%error="800095";%:TFSSERVER.Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.prc_iCounterGetNext: Counter with name %counterName="BuildFolderId";% does not exist

%error="901004";%:TFSSERVER.Tfs_DefaultCollection.prc_iiEnsureFolder: Database Update Failure - Error %error="800095";% executing EXEC statement for prc_iCounterGetNext

%error="901004";%:TFSSERVER.Tfs_DefaultCollection.prc_AddDefinition: Database Update Failure - Error %error="901004";% executing EXEC statement for Build.prc_iiEnsureFolder
```

It's strangly similar to 
[developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/23451/tfs2017-queue-new-build-error-500-error800095test.html)
witch have been resovle by executing a query on sql database given in the 
[TFS2017Update1 release note - known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-update1#-known-issues):

```
INSERT  tbl_Counter (PartitionId, DataspaceId, CounterName, CounterValue)
SELECT  DISTINCT
      dpm.PartitionId,
      ds.DataspaceId,
      N'TaskReferenceId',
      1
FROM    tbl_DatabasePartitionMap dpm
INNER LOOP JOIN Task.tbl_Hub h
ON      h.PartitionId = dpm.PartitionId
INNER LOOP JOIN tbl_Dataspace ds
ON      ds.PartitionId = dpm.PartitionId
      AND ds.DataspaceCategory = h.DataspaceCategory
      AND ds.DataspaceIdentifier <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
WHERE   dpm.PartitionId > 0
      AND dpm.HostType = 4
      AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT  *
          FROM    tbl_Counter c
          WHERE   c.PartitionId = dpm.PartitionId
                  AND c.DataspaceId = ds.DataspaceId
                  AND c.CounterName = N'TaskReferenceId'
      )
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found my way through this problem

1. How to know the correct DataspaceId:

   `SELECT TOP 1000 [PartitionId] ,[ProjectId],[DataspaceId],
   [ProjectUri],ProjectName],[SequenceId],[IsDeleted], 
   [IsResolutionStateCustomized],[IsFailureTypeCustomized],[MigrationState], 
   [MigrationError] FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Project] 
   WHERE 
   ProjectName = "My project witch having an error"`

The end of string in the column `[ProjectUri]`  contains the unique id of the project (in my case `vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/b96fbc5b-7bf3-452b-894f-6f5b4bb801c0`)

1. How to know the corresponding DataspaceId

   `SELECT TOP 1000 [PartitionId]
     ,[DataspaceCategory]
     ,[DataspaceIdentifier]
     ,[DataspaceId]
     ,[DatabaseId]
     ,[State]
     FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Dataspace]
     where DataspaceIdentifier="b96fbc5b-7bf3-452b-894f-6f5b4bb801c0"
     and DataspaceCategory="Build"`

It gave me my Dataspace ID : 726

2. Check if there is no record in the table [Build].[tbl_Folder]

   `SELECT TOP 1000 [PartitionId]
       ,[DataspaceId]
       ,[FolderId]
       ,[FolderPath]
       ,[FolderName]
       ,[CreatedBy]
       ,[CreatedOn]
       ,[Description]
       ,[ChangedBy]
       ,[ChangedOn]
       ,[Deleted]
       FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[Build].[tbl_Folder]
       WHERE DataspaceId=726`

If there is no record, i have to create one.

```
INSERT INTO [Build].[tbl_Folder]
       ([PartitionId]
       ,[DataspaceId]
       ,[FolderId]
       ,[FolderPath]
       ,[FolderName]
       ,[CreatedBy]
       ,[CreatedOn]
       ,[Description]
       ,[ChangedBy]
       ,[ChangedOn]
       ,[Deleted])
 VALUES
       (1
       ,726
       ,1
       ,''
       ,'\'
       ,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,0)
GO
```

4. Check if there is no record in the table [tbl_Counter] with this DataspaceId

   `SELECT TOP 1000 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]
   FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Counter]
   where CounterName='BuildFolderId' and DataspaceId=726`

If there is no record, i have to create one.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter]
       ([PartitionId]
       ,[DataspaceId]
       ,[CounterName]
       ,[CounterValue])
 VALUES
       (1
       ,726
       ,'BuildFolderId'
       ,2)
 GO
```

After that, i am able to save my build definition.

Other error appears when i try to **launch** my build definition:

```
%error="800095";%:TFSSERVER.Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.prc_iCounterGetNext: Counter with name %counterName="TimelineStringId";% does not exist
```

based on the previous script i insert new value in the table [tbl_Counter]

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter]
       ([PartitionId]
       ,[DataspaceId]
       ,[CounterName]
       ,[CounterValue])
 VALUES
       (1
       ,726
       ,'TimelineStringId'
       ,2)
 GO
```

Finally i have one remaing error:

```
%error="800095";%:TFSSERVER.Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.prc_iCounterGetNext: Counter with name %counterName="TaskOrchestrationPlanId";% does not exist
```

so:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter]
       ([PartitionId]
       ,[DataspaceId]
       ,[CounterName]
       ,[CounterValue])
 VALUES
       (1
       ,726
       ,'TaskOrchestrationPlanId'
       ,2)
 GO
```

I'm finally able to launch successfully my build definition.

Hope that could help someone.

i write a sql script in two version, one for TFS2018 and one other for TFS2015

**change the variable @projectName by your real project name.**
*The TFS2018 version:*

```
USE [Tfs_DefaultCollection]
GO
declare @projectUriGlobal varchar(max);
declare @projectName varchar(max);
declare @DataspaceIdentifier varchar(max);
declare @DataspaceId int;
select @projectName='MyProjectName'
select @projectUriGlobal = (select [ProjectUri] from [tbl_Project] where ProjectName=@projectName)
select @DataspaceIdentifier = (select right(@projectUriGlobal, charindex('/', reverse(@projectUriGlobal) + '/') - 1))
if not exists(select DataspaceId from [tbl_Dataspace] where DataspaceIdentifier = @DataspaceIdentifier and DataspaceCategory='Build')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Création d" un enregistrement dans [tbl_Dataspace] pour le DataspaceIdentifier '+@DataspaceIdentifier;
  INSERT INTO [tbl_Dataspace] VALUES (1,'Build', @DataspaceIdentifier,1,1)
END

select  @DataspaceId = (select DataspaceId from [tbl_Dataspace] where DataspaceIdentifier = @DataspaceIdentifier and DataspaceCategory='Build')

PRINT 'Project Name : '+@projectName;
PRINT 'Project Uri :'+  @projectUriGlobal
PRINT 'DataspaceIdentifier : '+ @DataspaceIdentifier
PRINT 'DataSpaceID : '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar)

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [DataspaceId] FROM [Build].[tbl_Folder] where DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans [Build].[tbl_Folder] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' car existe déjà'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [Build].[tbl_Folder] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar)
  INSERT INTO [Build].[tbl_Folder] ([PartitionId] ,[DataspaceId],[FolderId],[FolderPath],[FolderName],[CreatedBy],[CreatedOn],[Description],[ChangedBy],[ChangedOn],[Deleted])
        VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,1,'','\','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL ,NULL,NULL,0)
END

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName] FROM [tbl_Counter]  where CounterName='BuildFolderId' and DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=BuildFolderId  car existe déjà';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=BuildFolderId';
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter] ([PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]) VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,'BuildFolderId',2)
END

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName] FROM [tbl_Counter]  where CounterName='TimelineStringId' and DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TimelineStringId  car existe déjà';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TimelineStringId';
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter] ([PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]) VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,'TimelineStringId',2)
END

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName] FROM [tbl_Counter]  where CounterName='TaskOrchestrationPlanId' and DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TaskOrchestrationPlanId  car existe déjà';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TaskOrchestrationPlanId';
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter] ([PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]) VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,'TaskOrchestrationPlanId',2)
END
```

*And the version for TFS2015 would be*

```
USE [Tfs_DefaultCollection]
GO
declare @projectUriGlobal varchar(max);
declare @projectName varchar(max);
declare @DataspaceIdentifier varchar(max);
declare @DataspaceId int;

select @projectName='MyProjectName'
select @projectUriGlobal = (select [ProjectUri] from [tbl_Project] where ProjectName=@projectName)
select @DataspaceIdentifier = (select right(@projectUriGlobal, charindex('/', reverse(@projectUriGlobal) + '/') - 1))
if not exists(select DataspaceId from [tbl_Dataspace] where DataspaceIdentifier = @DataspaceIdentifier and DataspaceCategory='Build')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Création d" un enregistrement dans [tbl_Dataspace] pour le DataspaceIdentifier '+@DataspaceIdentifier;
  INSERT INTO [tbl_Dataspace] VALUES (1,'Build', @DataspaceIdentifier,1,1)
END

select  @DataspaceId = (select DataspaceId from [tbl_Dataspace] where DataspaceIdentifier = @DataspaceIdentifier and DataspaceCategory='Build')

PRINT 'Project Name : '+@projectName;
PRINT 'Project Uri :'+  @projectUriGlobal
PRINT 'DataspaceIdentifier : '+ @DataspaceIdentifier
PRINT 'DataSpaceID : '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar)

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName] FROM [tbl_Counter]  where CounterName='BuildFolderId' and DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=BuildFolderId  car existe déjà';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=BuildFolderId';
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter] ([PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]) VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,'BuildFolderId',2)
END

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName] FROM [tbl_Counter]  where CounterName='TimelineStringId' and DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TimelineStringId  car existe déjà';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TimelineStringId';
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter] ([PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]) VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,'TimelineStringId',2)
END

if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName] FROM [tbl_Counter]  where CounterName='TaskOrchestrationPlanId' and DataspaceId=@DataspaceId)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Pas d"enregistrement a creer dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TaskOrchestrationPlanId  car existe déjà';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creation d"un enregistrement dans la table [tbl_Counter] pour le dataspace ID '+ CAST(@DataspaceId as varchar) +' avec le counterName=TaskOrchestrationPlanId';
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Counter] ([PartitionId],[DataspaceId],[CounterName],[CounterValue]) VALUES (1,@DataspaceId,'TaskOrchestrationPlanId',2)
END
```